# Не отображается картинка для фона сайта

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6 color #333;
}

*:before *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}


/*CONTAINER*/

.container {
  width: 100% max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200p;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("../images/intro.jpeg") centre no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>ARCANE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="intro">

    <div class="container">
      <h1> ARCANE </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: уберите картинку и добавьте html и css сюда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас опечатка в строке

```
 background: url("../images/intro.jpeg") centre no-repeat;
```

> **centre** no-repeat

Исправьте её, и все заработает.

```
 background: url("../images/intro.jpeg") center no-repeat;
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!!! Помогло

Comment: Правильно я  вопрос закрыл?

Comment: @bdecb да, всё верно

Comment: Спасибо еще раз.